# CRM Dynamics. Set Default view for appropriate security role

Tags: view, dynamics-crm, crm, roles

Is it possible to set custom view as default for security role?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not really. System views are nowhere related to be driven by security roles like forms/dashboards. The closest one can be either keep the view in a Dashboard and the dashboard can be controlled by security role. [Read more](https://powerobjects.com/tips-and-tricks/using-security-roles-to-disable-custom-and-system-dashboards/)

Otherwise, create Personal view to share with a Team, for each security role need - create a Team (1-1) for easy mapping/sharing.